# nesting select boxes

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am looking for a way to nest select elements, meaning i would like to have the selection from the parent box determine the options found in the child box. For instance, the parent box will have a list of US states and the child box should have only cities found in the state selected, ie if the parent box is california, the cities available in city selection box should be only cities from california.  i know this is possible, but i am wondering what exactly is the easiest way to accomplish this type of nested selection boxes.  thanks.

Comment: Generally spoken: You need to catch the selection events (using JS) of your parent box, read its selected value and modify the available options of your child select boxes accordingly. Which technical approaches did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are familiar with Ajax, you can use Ajax call,

```
    <script>
        function getCities(stateID){
           // your ajax code stuff here

      }
  </script>

<select onselect="getCities(this.value)">
<options value="1">State A </option>
<options value="2">State B </option>
<options value="3">State C </option>
</select>

<div class="citieslist">

</div>
```

Using ajax display Cities in **citieslist** div